# Read Fault Registers from BeagleBone Black

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am writing ARM Assembly to run baremetal on the BeagleBone Black. I am using JTAG through the XDS110 Debug Probe, and am able to run basic assembly programs on the board.

My main question concerns trying to read the various status registers that are present in the Beaglebone's processor. I am referring to the arm documentation and their use of the MRC/MCR commands to read/write from these registers. See link below (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0198/e/programmer-s-model/register-descriptions/fault-status-registers-c5)

However, despite following the documentation, I am unable to read these values when running the commands on Beaglebone Black. Specifically, when I run the following command(s):

`MCR p15, #0, r7, c5, c0, #1   ; Write IFSR`

`MRC P15, #0, r12, c5, c0, #1  ; Read IFSR`

I get the following error, and the entire program stops executing:

`Break at address "0x20080" with no debug information available, or outside of program code.`

Does anybody have any ideas on how to read the fault status registers via baremetal ARM assembly on the Beaglebone Black? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are running this in an application on linux?  I assume you dont have permission at that layer.  Did you confirm this in the arm docs?

Comment: The editor is being run in Windows, but the application itself is being run baremetal on the Beaglebone via JTAG; ie. The on-board Linux OS is not turned on.